# I want to fetch record from table using postgres but it consist inside jsonarray

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to fetch device name on basis of department id which is inside array

```
select device_name 
where departmentIDs = 1
```

Sample data:

```
device_to_department_id | device_name   |  department_ids
-----------------------------------------------------------------
                      1 | xyz           | {"departmentIDs":[1,2]}
```

Comment: Do you want those rows that have **only** the ID = 1 or those that have _at least_ that ID (but could have more)

Comment: i want to fetch device_name whose department id is 1 but department id is inside jsonArray

Comment: So you want to return rows that contain department ID 1 **and** can contain additional IDs?

Answer (score 0):

select distinct device_name from device_to_department_table t, json_array_elements(department_ids -> 'departmentIDs') e where e::text::int in (1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains operator:

```
select *
from device_to_department_table 
where department_ids  @> '{"departmentIDs":[1]}'
```

This would return all rows that contain *at least* the department ID 1 (so your sample row with `[1,2]` would be included)